# It's Posibel create a class for Appbar in Flet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flutter, flet

I Try to make deffrent class for appbar in flet. as you know in main function we can change property after page.appbar= change property here ( writing code ).

I want create diffrent class for appbar properties , something like that

```
class Header(ft.UserControl):


def build(self):

    header_f = ft.AppBar(
        leading=ft.Icon(ft.icons.PALETTE),
        leading_width=40,
        title=ft.Text("AppBar Example"),)
    return header_f
```

and make object in main function like this

```
def main(page: ft.page):

heder = Header()
page.appbar = heder

page.update()
```

but it's not work.
Any one can tell me it's possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem: I just edit this line

```
heder = Header()
```

to

```
heder = Header().build()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
in Main:
`bar = AppbarApp(page).build()`

in Class:

```
class AppbarApp(UserControl):
    def __init__(self,page):
        super().__init__()
        self.page=page
```